# Установка модуля PHP

Tags: установка, windows, php

Здравствуйте! Такая беда: установила модуль PHP на Windows 7 (сервер ставила Apache 2.2), мучилась со связями, но поставила и все работает. А на Windows 7 Starter модуль не ставится (сервер поставился нормально). Почему? Вообще возможно ли его на Starter установить?

Comment: Уточните модуль, ошибки, процесс установки.

Answer (score 1):

Возможно проблема в MS Office. А именно, нужно убрать службы публикации и SharePoint. Также не должны быть включены службы ISS.Одновременно один порт может использовать только одно приложение. Не используя сторонних утилит можно проверить кто занимает порт командой netstat -anb